# Ubuntu Microphone and Speaker not detecting

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, settings, speakers

I just upgraded to ubuntu 22.10 from 22.04 and I noticed that it was not detecting my speakers and micrphone. I tried connecting it to a bluetooth earphone just to check if it even works, but even that failed.
I have attached some pictures regarding this, can someone help?

[image: Ubuntu sound settings]

[image: Output device selector]

Comment: Can you post more details about your hardware/laptop model?

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (long term support) will be supported until 2027, whereas Ubuntu 22.10 will lose support in July 2023. Can you check if Ubuntu 23.04 (supported until January 2023) fixes the issue. I would suggest you to check that from a live USB, and fresh install if sound works. Otherwise, revert back to 22.04, since it is an LTS version.

Comment: can you click on the speaker icon on the menu bar, select Sound Settings and select the input/output device

Comment: My laptop is an asus vivobook 15 amd a12, 8gb ram and 512 gb ssd also I am updating to 23,04 just to check if it fixes the solution. If that doesnt help I am going to revert back to 22.04 thanks for your help :). Also the speaker doesnt show up on the menu bar because its not getting detected or something idk very well.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 fixed it.